# How to monitor, send alert for Long running Jobs in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, monitoring

I have a requirement, where I need to monitor hadoop job (Hive/Map Reduce, spark ) that are running for long, may be say 3 hr duration in the cluster. I know I can view all these jobs in UI, but I need to monitor it every hourly or 30 min and send email/alerts if job is running for more then 3 hours. Is there a way to do this. 
My environment is HDP 2.6

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Oozie. Oozie allows you to configure alerts if a job exceeds it's expected run-time.

In order to use this feature you'd have to submit your job as an Oozie workflow.

http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_Overview.html
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/DG_SLAMonitoring.html#SLA_Definition_in_Workflow

Answer (score 0):

as tk421 mentions - oozie is the "right" way to do this in the context of hadoop.

however, if you do not require all the overhead, something simple like an on-demand watchdog timer might be sufficient (ie: [wdt.io](http://wdt.io)) .  Basically the workflow is send the start signal, start the job, and send an end signal when the job completes.  IF the second signal does not come in within the allotted amount of time an email / sms alert is dispatched.

This method would work for non-hadoop workflows as well.